# Comparing arrays with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have two arrays, one is a simple array like this:

```
["Adrian", "Jhon"]
```

And the another array is an array of objects which I converted from a jSon object. The original jSon was this:

```
[
    {
        "Nome": "Jhon",
        "Departamento": "Test"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Adrian",
        "Departamento": "Test"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Jessy",
        "Departamento": "Test"
    }
]
```

Now I need to compare the first array, with second one. If the `Nome` attribute match with my first array, I will return the entire object to another array of objects.

**How can I do it with jQuery or pure JavaScript keeping the order of the first array?**

**EDIT - For stop taking downvotes**

I already tried this:

```
jQuery.each(array, function (x) {
     novoRepo.push(jQuery.grep(repositorio, function (a) {
          return a.Nome == array[x];
     }));
});
```

But I get an exception saying that a.Nome is undefined.

Comment: @Curt Correct form: Have you done any steps to try to solve the issue by yourself? We would like to see those as it could help the solving process and prevent us from doing the same things if they were unsuccessful.

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/P975R/ I don't understand the question :|

Comment: [Your code works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/X4uWR/1/). What did I do different?

Comment: I forgot to say, I need to keep the order like the first array, this is very important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a filter you can do this:

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3RFGP/)

```
var found = [];
$.each(["Jhon","Adrian"],function(i, name) {
  $.each(otherObject,function(j,obj) {
    if (obj.Nome==name) found.push(obj); // you could leave if only one of each
  });
});
```

Comment: Also `$(this)` looks wrong, simply use `this.Nome` or `function(z,x) {}` and then `x.Nome`

Comment: I like your fiddle.  You are allowing the OP to keep the same look/feel with json object, and keeping the coding to a minimum. good job.

Comment: @NULL please revert down vote - I was fixing my code while you commented/downvoted (assuming you downvoted)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [Array `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var search = ["Jhon","Adrian"],
    data = [
        {"Nome": "Jhon", "Departamento": "Test"},
        {"Nome": "Adrian", "Departamento": "Test"},
        {"Nome": "Jessy", "Departamento": "Test"}
    ];
var result = data.filter(function(obj) {
    return search.indexOf(obj.Nome) >= 0;
});
```

For those browsers not supporting [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) or [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) (notably IE<9) you can either shim them or use the jQuery equivalents [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep) and [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) (see @NULL's answer below for explicit code).

---

To preserve the order of the `search` array and not of the `data` one, you can use `map` when for every search name there is exactly one result in the `data`:

```
result = search.map(function(name) {
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        if (data[i].Nome == name)
            return data[i];
});
```

If there can be none or multiple results for each name, you better used `concatMap`:

```
result = Array.prototype.concat.apply(null, search.map(function(name) {
    return data.filter(function(obj) {
         return obj.Nome == name;
    });
});
```

or with [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) which does automatically unwrap arrays:

```
result = $.map(search, function(name) {
    return $.grep(data, function(obj) {
         return obj.Nome == name;
    });
});
```

Comment: One thing to note, IE<9 doesn't have an `.indexOf()` function for Array

Comment: @mplungjan: Shouldn't make any difference, only the for-loop vs. native map/indexOf vs. jQuery each. However, the OP seems to need a special order so looping `search` first is required.

Comment: I counted. my innerloop seems to count to 6 anyway, unless I leave when found

Comment: @mplungjan: Oh, right, because `indexOf` stops when something is found, the solution might be faster if many searched names do exist in the data. However, the algorithmic complexity is the same.

Answer (score 2):

[To extend @Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17298049/887539)

Using `$.grep` and `$.inArray` would look like this:

```
var search = ["Jhon","Adrian"],
    data = [
        {"Nome": "Jhon", "Departamento": "Test"},
        {"Nome": "Adrian", "Departamento": "Test"},
        {"Nome": "Jessy", "Departamento": "Test"}
    ];
var result = $.grep(data, function(obj) {
    return $.inArray(obj.Nome, search) >= 0;
});
```

Comment: Yes, if you make sure that >= jQuery 1.2 is included.